# Python zipfile, How to set the compression level?

Tags: python, zip, zlib

Python supports zipping files when zlib is available, `ZIP_DEFLATE`

see:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/zipfile.html

The `zip` command-line program on Linux supports `-1` fastest, `-9` best.

Is there a way to set the compression level of a zip file created in Python's `zipfile` module?

Comment: This is currently not implemented, see also: http://bugs.python.org/issue21417

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Starting from python 3.7, the `zipfile` module added the `compresslevel` parameter.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

I know this question is dated, but for people like me, that fall in this question, it may be a better option than the accepted one.

Answer (score 9):

Python 3.7+ answer: If you look at the [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/08254be6c5324416081cc28a047b377e1f4ed644/Doc/library/zipfile.rst) docs you'll see:

```python
""" Class with methods to open, read, write, close, list zip files.

z = ZipFile(file, mode="r", compression=ZIP_STORED, allowZip64=True,
            compresslevel=None)

file: Either the path to the file, or a file-like object.
      If it is a path, the file will be opened and closed by ZipFile.
mode: The mode can be either read 'r', write 'w', exclusive create 'x',
      or append 'a'.
compression: ZIP_STORED (no compression), ZIP_DEFLATED (requires zlib),
             ZIP_BZIP2 (requires bz2) or ZIP_LZMA (requires lzma).
allowZip64: if True ZipFile will create files with ZIP64 extensions when
            needed, otherwise it will raise an exception when this would
            be necessary.
compresslevel: None (default for the given compression type) or an integer
               specifying the level to pass to the compressor.
               When using ZIP_STORED or ZIP_LZMA this keyword has no effect.
               When using ZIP_DEFLATED integers 0 through 9 are accepted.
               When using ZIP_BZIP2 integers 1 through 9 are accepted.

"""
```

which means you can pass the desired compression in the constructor:

```python
myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(file_handle, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9)
```

See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 7):

The `zipfile` module does not provide this. During compression it uses constant from `zlib` - `Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION`. By default it equals -1. So you can try to change this constant manually, as possible solution.

Comment: Not so nice (or threadsafe). but this seems to be the only way.

Comment: "Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION represents a default compromise between speed and compression (currently equivalent to level 6)."  -- python 3.6 docs. so its not a bad default

Comment: To precise [@Tritium21 reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526155/python-zipfile-how-to-set-the-compression-level#comment75667517_27526410): https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/zlib.html#zlib.compress